# npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript

Tags: json, node.js

Newbie node question. I am not able to get my project running anymore.

{
      "name": "MyApp",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start": "node app.js dev2"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "async-await": "^0.1.32",
        "asyncawait": "^1.0.3",
        "body-parser": "^1.14.2",
        "deasync": "*",
        "ejs": "^2.4.1",
        "express": "^4.13.4",
        "gulp": "^3.9.0",
        "gulp-concat": "*",
        "gulp-filelist": "^0.2.0",
        "gulp-foreach": "^0.1.0",
        "gulp-remove-files": "0.0.3",
        "gulp-rename": "*",
        "gulp-uglify": "*",
        "gulp-watch": "^4.3.5",
        "mongoose": "^4.4.1",
        "mongoose-ttl": "0.0.3",
        "node-inspector": "^0.12.5",
        "promise": "^7.1.1",
        "rootpath": "^0.1.2"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "browser-sync": "^2.11.1",
        "gulp": "^3.9.1"
      }
    }

```
1726 error Failed to parse json
1726 error Unexpected token '\u0000' at 1:1
1726 error 
1726 error ^
1727 error File: C:\Users\dir\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\accepts\1.2.13\package\package.json
1728 error Failed to parse package.json data.
1728 error package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error Unexpected token '\u0000' at 1:1

seems that u have null character at first line and 1 character

can u provide package.json on pastebin or similar?

Comment: I browsed to the file and I all I see is a bunch of null strings! This is leading to something. I am not sure how that file got messed up. I tried deleting it and I get a different error after it creates a new one

Comment: npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.3.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! file C:\Users\dir\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\escape-html\1.0.3\package\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE

npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token '\u0000' at 1:1

Comment: looks like every new file it points to has a bunch of null strings null null null null null null....

Comment: Also, just `checkout` files using git/svn/etc

Comment: Ok fixed it by uninstalling node and removing the following directories "C:\Users\dir\AppData\Roaming\npm" and "C:\Users\dir\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" then installing node again. However, I am not sure what caused it, I use brackets as my editor.

Comment: Never seen that before, but seems something like encoding/decoding trouble. Git rocks :)